# How to make sure inputs can be diveded by batch size in stateful LSTM?

Tags: r, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm

I'm having some issues training a network using stateful LSTMs.
Given the code below, I'm getting the following error message:

```
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: In a stateful network, you should only pass inputs with a number of samples that can be divided by the batch size. Found: 9384 samples
```

Input is sent from an external application, so I cannot control the exact number of inputs sent. What would be the best way to ensure that the input can always be divided nu the batch size?

```
neural.train = function(model,XY) 
{
  XY <- as.matrix(XY)
  X <- XY[,-ncol(XY)]
  Y <- XY[,ncol(XY)]
  Y <<- ifelse(Y > 0,1,0)

  dropout <- 0.3
  batchSize <- 64

  newModel <- keras_model_sequential() 

  newModel %>%
    layer_lstm(batch_input_shape =  c(batchSize, 30, 19), units = 72, return_sequences = TRUE, stateful = TRUE, dropout = dropout, recurrent_dropout = dropout) %>%
    #layer_dense(units = 20) %>%
    #layer_lstm(units = 50, return_sequences = TRUE, stateful = TRUE, dropout = dropout, recurrent_dropout = dropout) %>% 
    layer_lstm(units = 16, dropout = dropout, recurrent_dropout = dropout, return_sequences = FALSE, stateful = TRUE) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 8) %>% 
    layer_batch_normalization() %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'relu')

  newModel %>% compile( 
    optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 0.001),
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    metrics = c('accuracy')
  )

  #X_conv <- matrix(c(X[1,1:10],X[1,11:20]),ncol=10,nrow=2)
  ar <- array(X,c(dim(X)[1],30,19))
  #newModel %>% fit(X, Y, epochs=20, batch_size=100, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle=TRUE, callbacks=reduce_lr)
  newModel %>% fit(ar, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=batchSize, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle=FALSE)
  Models[[model]] <<-  serialize_model(newModel, include_optimizer = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Likely by finding the *largest* divisor of your number of inputs, and using that!  That would be a real shame if you had some extremely large prime, ha!